# Prevent Hashtable from converting to ASCII

Tags: java, android, ascii, hashtable

I am running a hashtable in an Android app that I am developing. When I run the activity it is converting the content of "ht" into ASCII characters. Does anyone know a way to prevent this from happening?

Basically, I need to decode the encoded text and use the result in a string. In order to work the URL that is used in the string cannot have encoded text in it.

**Hashtable**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void executeAsyncTask(){
 Hashtable<String,String> ht=new Hashtable<String,String>();
 GetDeptAyncTask async=new GetDeptAyncTask();
  ht.put("?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1","&SEARCH=test");
  try {
    URLDecoder.decode(""+ht, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   Hashtable[] ht_array={ht};
    async.execute(ht_array);
}
```

**Trying to use it in a string**

```
protected String doInBackground(Hashtable<String,String>... params) {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  Hashtable ht=params[0];
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  String json=HelperHttp.getJSONResponseFromURL(BaseUrl+"2013/export", ht);
```

**How "ht" is read in the "json" string**

```
?%3FTYPE%3DleagueSearch%26JSON%3D1=%26SEARCH%test
```

**How the URL is supposed to be read**

```
?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1&SEARCH=test
```

**LogCat for "ht"**

```
?:??: W/?(?): Hashtable {?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1=&SEARCH=test}
```

**LogCat for "json" string**

```
?:??: W/?(?): URL==>HIDDENURL/export?%3FTYPE%3DleagueSearch%26JSON%3D1=%26SEARCH%test

?:??: W/?(?): Json Response==><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">....

?:??: W/?(?):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:127)

?:??: W/?(?):   at myapp.app.MainActivity$GetDeptAyncTask.parseJsonString(MainActivity.java:80)
```

Comment: Are you sending this through HTTP ?

Comment: Yes. the "BaseUrl" string is set up as http://.... If that's what you mean.

Comment: I wanted to check if you are transmitting the Hashtable through HTTP protocal and looks like it is.. in that case all the content will be encoded

Comment: Is there any way around that other than using HTTPS?

Comment: If I leave set "ht" as ht.put("",""); the json string queries as BaseUrl+"2013/export?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1&SEARCH=test?" Is there a way to stop the extra question mark from being added to the end of the URL, while still structuring the string as such? (BaseUrl+"2013/export?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1&SEARCH=test", ht);

Comment: You can decode that string to get back original value, if thats all you want

Comment: Yeah. That should be all that I need? Would you be able to provide me with an example of how to do that? I'm not familiar with the best practice here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.net.URLDecoder` to decode the encoded text

```
URLDecoder.decode("%3FTYPE%3DleagueSearch%26JSON%3D1=%26SEARCH%3Dtest", "UTF-8")
```

will produce

```
?TYPE=leagueSearch&JSON=1=&SEARCH=test
```

Comment: Thank you! That should be right. I tried to add that but nothing changed. I am still getting the same output after changing it to this: http://pastie.org/7813425. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's really only useful after the string has been used. I need a way to decode the encoded text before it is placed in the string.